# How to create two colors gradient effect from center using css?

Tags: css, gradient

In excel I created this effect with a plus sign in it.
I have been looking to create this with CSS, but I am not getting close!
How can I do this? Is there any good web site that teaches how to work with gradients?

[image]
[image]

Regards,
Elio Fernandes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With CSS you can reach [Radial Gradient](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp), is similar, but not with Excel output.

```css
#grad1 {
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(red 5%, yellow 15%, green 60%);
  /* Safari 5.1-6.0 */
  background: -o-radial-gradient(red 5%, yellow 15%, green 60%);
  /* For Opera 11.6 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(red 5%, yellow 15%, green 60%);
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: radial-gradient(red 5%, yellow 15%, green 60%);
  /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}
```

```html
<div id="grad1"></div>
```

**Note**: Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions do not support gradients.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this particluar effect, using CSS gradients may not be the way to go since it's quite complex.

You could try this :

```css
.gradient {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: radial-gradient(#fff, #000)
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient"></div>
```

Here are some CSS references :

- [CSS Gradients](https://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/)
- [MDN - CSS Gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Images/Using_CSS_gradients)